# Horizontal ItemControl item's width to not exceed itemControl's width

Tags: xaml, itemscontrol

I can't figure out how to make an itemControl's item activate the horizontal scroll bar of the item control. My scenario is when there is only one item. A scrollbar appears when multiple items are present in the itemSource. But the item template is built in a way that each item is long enough to stretch beyond the width of the parent's width. I'm assuming I will need to use Pixel as my scrolling unit, but that is not making a difference.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LAndUDataPoints[0].Models, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LAndUItemTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollUnit="Pixel" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `ItemsControl` (and `ListBox`) does smart scrolling (jumping to each item as you scroll), but with one item it will just stay on the beginning of the first item (no scroll bar needed since there is no second item outside the visible window).

If you want a smoother scroll and keep the virtualization you should switch to use `TreeView`, eg:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LAndUDataPoints[0].Models, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LAndUItemTemplate}">
    <TreeView .ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView .ItemsPanel>
</TreeView >
```

In this case you don't need `ScrollUnit="Pixel"` on the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.